# How to get rid of app icons from appearing on Share?

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native

How do i exclude the **Instagram** and iOS **Messaging** app icon from displaying in Share? I can't find the string to disable it in `ExcludedActivityTypes`

```
import { Share } from 'react-native' 
. 
.
.

const result = await Share.share(

      {
        message: 'Check it out',
        title: "hey",
        url: "www.image....."
      },
      {
        // iOS only:
        excludedActivityTypes: [
                                'com.apple.UIKit.activity.PostToTwitter',
                                'com.apple.UIKit.activity.PostToWeibo',
                                'com.apple.UIKit.activity.Print',
                                'com.apple.UIKit.activity.CopyToPasteboard',
                                'com.apple.UIKit.activity.AssignToContact',
                                'com.apple.UIKit.activity.SaveToCameraRoll',
                                'com.apple.UIKit.activity.AddToReadingList',
                                'com.apple.UIKit.activity.PostToFlickr',
                                'com.apple.UIKit.activity.PostToVimeo',
                                'com.apple.UIKit.activity.PostToTencentWeibo',
                                'com.apple.UIKit.activity.AirDrop',
                                'com.apple.UIKit.activity.OpenInIBooks',
                                'com.apple.UIKit.activity.MarkupAsPDF',
                                'com.apple.reminders.RemindersEditorExtension',
                                'com.apple.mobilenotes.SharingExtension',
                                'com.apple.mobileslideshow.StreamShareService',
                                'com.linkedin.LinkedIn.ShareExtension',
                                'pinterest.ShareExtension',
                                'com.google.GooglePlus.ShareExtension',
                                'com.tumblr.tumblr.Share-With-Tumblr',
                                'net.whatsapp.WhatsApp.ShareExtension',
                                'com.facebook.Facebook.ShareExtension',

                               ],
      },
    )
```

A bonus would also be to get rid of '**Save To Files**' button

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The Instagram bundle identifier is `com.burbn.instagram`. The messaging app bundle identifier is `com.apple.MobileSMS`. I'm not certain about the *Save to Files* action, but try this: `com.apple.DocumentsApp`.

[Reference](https://support.apple.com/en-ca/guide/mdm/mdm90f60c1ce/web)

Comment: Unfortunately none of those worked. I tried: 'com.burbn.instagram.ShareExtension', but that didn't either